# Prevent users from seeing objects to which they have no access

Tags: postgresql, permissions, postgresql-9.5

**WHAT**

I have users that share a database, but have their own schemas. Each user is only able to access objects on their schema - they have been explicitly revoked usage on the schemas that are not theirs.

I am not concerned about a user inappropriately accessing others' schema; however, I would very much like for them not to be able to see the contents or even the existence of the other schema to which they have no access.

**WHY**

I am aware that this is mostly "cosmetic", but the primary reason for this would be that my users do not have to shift through objects that they cannot access in certain tools (Tableau, DB IDEs, etc) - so I think it does add some practical value.

**ATTEMPTS**

I've been searching for a solution, but haven't found one that works. For instance, I revoked users' access on `information_schema` and `pg_catalog` (I know this is not recommended); however, it had no effect.

---

Is this at all possible?

Comment: There was discussion of allowing row-level security to be enabled on system tables. I don't remember if it got included in 9.5. Have a play.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to limit access to pg_class, pg_attribute, or pg_proc. Therefore what you want can only be achieved by separating each user in their own databases rather than individual schemas.